# Prolog Recursion through Set of

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to work on this Prolog rule you pass in an input of a list of movies and it returns a list of a star that are involved in that particular movie.

**Predicate:**

```
starsin(captain_america,chris_evan).
starsin(avengers,chris_evan).
starsin(ant_man,chris_evan).
starsin(captain_marvel,chris_evan).
starsin(iron_man,chris_evan).
starsin(avengers,tom_holland).
starsin(captain_marvel,tom_holland).
starsin(captain_america,tom_holland).
starsin(iron_man,robert).
starsin(avengers,robert).
starsin(captain_america,robert).
```

I tried to use set of rule but somehow I cant figure out a way to use it recursively:

```
link([Head],Set) :-
   setof(Star1,starsin(Head,Star1),Set).
```

**Input and Output:**

```
link([ironman],Set).
Set=[chris_evan,robert]
```

Somehow I want to pass in more than one element in the list but I need to use recursive.

Is there anyway I could do it?

Comment: What happens if you have more than one movie?  Does your `link` predicate give the set of people who are in *all* of them movies, or do they just need to be in one of them?

Comment: so what I want is the input is the list of the movies and output will the list of stars that appears in that given movie

for example the input: [ captain_america, avengers , ant_man ] the output would be [chris_evan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-deterministic predicate `starsin(X, Y)` iff movie `X` includes film star `Y`.

Let's generalise this to tell us which stars appear in any of a list of movies.

```
movies_starsin(Movies, Star) :-
    member(Movie, Movies),
    starsin(Movie, Star).
```

Finally you want something like this:

```
movies_stars(Movies, Stars) :-
    setof(Star, movies_starsin(Movies, Star), Stars).
```

Hope this helps.

[UPDATE]

I had misunderstood the problem, which is to find the set of stars that appear in *all* movies in the given list.  Okay:

```
starsin_all([Movie | Movies], Star) :-
    % Star must appear in Movie.
    starsin(Movie, Star),
    % There can be no OtherMovie in which Star does not appear.
    \+ (
        member(OtherMovie, Movies),
        \+ starsin(OtherMovie, Star)
    ).

all_starsin_all(Movies, Stars) :-
    setof(Star, starsin_all(Movies, Star), Stars).
```

You could equivalently write `starsin_all` like this:

```
starsin_all([Movie | Movies], Star) :-
    starsin(Movie, Star),
    forall(member(OtherMovie, Movies), starsin(OtherMovie, Star)).
```

Cheers.

Comment: Sounds like they only want stars who are in *all* the movies given.

Comment: it somehow works but when i test it with the queries: movies_stars([ironman,avengers,captain_marvel,ant_man],Stars). it should only output as [chris_evan]. but in your code it ouput all the star in each movie

Comment: Ohhhh, you want the intersection of each movies' stars.  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: The special case of "no movies in the input list" is not covered, One needs to add the fact:  `starsin_all([], Actor) :- starsin(_, Actor).` .. I have allowed myself to add this solution to my little [github page](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/simple_db_op.md), which also contains unit test code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like `maplist/2`, which can be used find solution that work with *all* of the members of a list, which is what you want.  And then, because you want all the stars, maybe something like `findall/3`.

I'd advise changing `starsin` to put the actor first though, for two reasons:
  1. It makes more sense to say "Chris Evan stars in Iron Man" than the other way round.  E.g. Compare with, `member(X, S)` means "X is a member of S".
  2. It'll work easier with `maplist`.

Not going to give you the full solution, because this looks a bit homeworky. :)